# strings.xml:17: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix

Tags: android, android-xml

It initially had no errors. But showing errors without markers ever since I tried to sign and export it.

I checked many possible solutions on the net but none have worked. Please help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<resources
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"
    >
    <!-- Label for the "Done" button on the far left of action mode toolbars. -->
    <string name="abc_action_mode_done" translatable="false">Done</string>
<!-- Content description for the action bar "home" affordance. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_action_bar_home_description" translatable="false">Navigate home</string>
<!-- Content description for the action bar "up" affordance. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_action_bar_up_description" translatable="false">Navigate up</string>
<!-- Content description for the action menu overflow button. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_action_menu_overflow_description" translatable="false">More options</string>

<!-- Content description for the Toolbar icon used to collapse an expanded action mode. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_toolbar_collapse_description" translatable="false">Collapse</string>

<!-- Formatting string for describing the action bar's title/home/up affordance.
     This is a single tappable "button" that includes the app icon, the Up indicator
     (usually a "<" chevron) and the window title text.
     %1$s is the title. %2$s is the description of what tapping/clicking the whole
     thing is going to do. -->
<string name="abc_action_bar_home_description_format" translatable="false">%1$s, %2$s</string>
<!-- Just like action_bar_home_description_format, but this one will be used
     if the window is also providing subtitle text.
     %1$s is the title. %2$s is the subtitle. %3$s is the description of what
     tapping/clicking the whole thing is going to do. -->
<string name="abc_action_bar_home_subtitle_description_format" translatable="false">%1$s, %2$s, %3$s</string>

<!-- SearchView accessibility description for search button [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_searchview_description_search" translatable="false">Search</string>
<!-- SearchView accessibility description for search text field [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_searchview_description_query" translatable="false">Search query</string>
<!-- SearchView accessibility description for clear button [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_searchview_description_clear" translatable="false">Clear query</string>
<!-- SearchView accessibility description for submit button [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_searchview_description_submit" translatable="false">Submit query</string>
<!-- SearchView accessibility description for voice button [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_searchview_description_voice" translatable="false">Voice search</string>

<!-- ActivityChooserView - accessibility support -->
<!-- Description of the shwoing of a popup window with activities to choose from. [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_activitychooserview_choose_application">Choose an app</string>
<!-- Title for a button to expand the list of activities in ActivityChooserView [CHAR LIMIT=25] -->
<string name="abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all">See all</string>
<!-- Description of a share target (both in the list of such or the default share button) in a ShareActionProvider (share UI). [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with_application">Share with %s</string>
<!-- Description of the choose target button in a ShareActionProvider (share UI). [CHAR LIMIT=NONE] -->
<string name="abc_shareactionprovider_share_with">Share with</string>
```

The errors:

```
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_action_bar_home_description' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_action_bar_home_description_format' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_action_bar_home_subtitle_description_format' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_action_bar_up_description' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_action_menu_overflow_description' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_action_mode_done' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_activity_chooser_view_see_all' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_activitychooserview_choose_application' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_searchview_description_clear' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_searchview_description_query' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_searchview_description_search' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_searchview_description_submit' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_searchview_description_voice' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_shareactionprovider_share_with' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] warning: string 'abc_shareactionprovider_share_with_application' has no default translation.
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX] F:\Edge15\appcompat_v7\res\values\strings.xml:17: error: Error parsing XML: unbound prefix
[2015-03-05 01:32:31 - GEEKONIX]
```

Comment: And yet no problem is being shown on the appcompat_v7 project.

Comment: you are getting a lint error just remove that, everything is ok with your app

Comment: Not working. I also noticed that R.java is not being generated anymore.

Comment: when there is an error you can't generate R.java. if there is not error in java code then check your resources in xml that must be causing the problem

Comment: The app was working properly. The only change made was trying to export a signed app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow while trying to sign the app eclipse removed this line from most xml files.

xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"

On adding back this line to the xml files the project worked again

Answer (score 1):

go to preferences and ignore lint errors by changing them to fatal to ignore and then clean the project will work ...

[image]

because it is giving you error you are not able to generate R.java because of which all your resources are unallocated

Comment: in which xml file are you facing this issue

Comment: in all the layout xmls

Answer (score 0):

Either remove `tools:ignore="MissingTranslation"` from the root element or add `xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"` to the root element. Your `tools` prefix is undefined at the moment.

Comment: Has no effect whatsoever. R.java is not being generated. And thus 198 errors of "cannot be resolved or is not a field".